# What is the strongest statement that can be deduced, using Chebyshev’s inequality, about $p$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with expectation and variance both equal to $20$. Let $p = P (10 < X < 30)$.
What is the strongest statement that can be deduced, using Chebyshev’s inequality, about $p$? 
a. $p≥0.80$ b. $p≥0.20$ c. $p≤0.68$ d. $p≤0.80$ e. $p≥0.68$ f. $p≤0.20$

Chebyshev’s inequality is $P(|X-\mu|≥a)≤\frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$. 
Someone has an idea of how to find the strongest statement? (A)

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$P(10<X<30)=P(|X-20|<10)=P(|X-\mu|<10)=1-P(|X-\mu|\geq 10)$$
By Chebyshev's inequality, we have
$$P(X-\mu|\geq 10)\leq \frac{20}{10^{2}}=.2$$
Therefore
$$P(10<X<30)=1-P(|X-\mu|\geq 10)\geq 1-.2=.8$$